# iOS : How to enable Audio directions on Google Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, google-maps

I am using the below code to open Google Maps from my iOS application where I am passing starting and End point of places.

It navigates correctly from start point to end point but does not guide through **Audio (voice)**.

I want to enable voice guidance facility.

please help

```
ClientState *clientState = [ClientState sharedInstance];            
CLLocation *currentLocation = clientState.currentLocation;            

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maps://maps.google.com/?xyz=xyz&saddr=%1.8f,%1.8f&daddr=%@,%@",
         currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, trip.pickupLatitude, trip.pickupLongitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

Comment: are you using ios 6? it doesn't support voice control ios 5 does

Comment: HOw can I achieve this in iOS 6 ... or any authentic link ..?

Comment: not possible in ios6 sorry not yet anyway

Comment: thanks Rachel ..How can I achieve this by using any other maps

Comment: it's not a limitation of google maps on ios6, it's just the ios6 platform itself that has the limitation. it's listed as an issue on the apple support forums. I don't think you can implement it. Sorry! :(

Comment: iOS 6 does provide full voice navigation.  It does not work on the iPhone 4, but works on Siri-enabled devices.

Comment: voice direction is not working on iPhone 6 version 12.0.1 and 11.4.1. If anyone found solution then please provide link. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maps app will handle audio guidance for you.  You do not need to enable it.  If you open the Apple Maps URL scheme or Google Maps app, it will guide the user via audio if they have their audio turned on.  Voice directions only work on certain phones for the Apple Maps App.  The iPhone 5 and 4S have voice direction, while the iPhone 4 and 3GS do not.  Just like there is no Siri on iPhone 4, there is no Siri Voice Navigation.

See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4312963?start=15&tstart=0) on Apple for extra discussion.